# Virtuemart componet 1.1.5 -authoriz.net -joomla

Tags: components, joomla1.5, virtuemart

Error: 3-2-13-P---(TESTMODE) The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive.
Error: Failure in Processing the Payment (ps_authorize)

I'm getting this kind of typical error while i'm checkout order.....
I've done all the process that need for Authorize payment gateway....
both the component are in test mode...even i've apply API login id and transaction key..
still this kind of error occurs....

help me out.. my project deadline is on my head...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the API login and transaction key correct, most likely you are querying the incorrect server. In Virtuemart > Store > List Payment Methods > Credit Card > Configuration check your Authorize.net Server Hostname. In test mode it should be test.authorize.net and secure.authorize.net for live transactions.